# Torque Job Stuck with mpirun

Tags: linux, mpi, batch-processing, pbs, torque

I ran the following PBS script to run a job with my newly configured Torque:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N asyn
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=2
#PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cat $PBS_NODEFILE>nodes
mpirun -np 4 gmx_mpi mdrun -deffnm asyn_10ns
```

It gets stuck with an R status. The time remains 00:00:00. When I checked the tracejob, it gets me the following details:

```
[root@headnode ~]# tracejob 11
/var/spool/torque/mom_logs/20170825: No such file or directory

Job: 11.headnode

08/25/2017 13:49:31.230 S    enqueuing into batch, state 1 hop 1
08/25/2017 13:49:31.360 S    Job Modified at request of root@headnode
08/25/2017 13:49:31.373 L    Job Run
08/25/2017 13:49:31.361 S    Job Run at request of root@headnode
08/25/2017 13:49:31.374 S    Not sending email: User does not want mail of this type.
08/25/2017 13:49:31  A    queue=batch
08/25/2017 13:49:31  A    user=souparno group=souparno jobname=asyn queue=batch ctime=1503649171 qtime=1503649171 etime=1503649171
                          start=1503649171 owner=souparno@headnode exec_host=headnode3/0-1+headnode2/0-1 Resource_List.nodes=2:ppn=2
                          Resource_List.walltime=120:00:00 Resource_List.nodect=2 Resource_List.neednodes=2:ppn=2
```

The sched_log is giving me the following details:

```
08/25/2017 13:49:31.373;64; pbs_sched.25166;Job;11.headnode;Job Run
```

The server_log gives the following output:

```
08/25/2017 13:49:31.230;256;PBS_Server.25216;Job;11.headnode;enqueuing into batc
h, state 1 hop 1
08/25/2017 13:49:31.230;08;PBS_Server.25216;Job;perform_commit_work;job_id: 11.headnode
08/25/2017 13:49:31.230;02;PBS_Server.25216;node;close_conn;Closing connection 8 and calling its accompanying function on close
08/25/2017 13:49:31.360;08;PBS_Server.25134;Job;11.headnode;Job Modified at request of root@headnode
08/25/2017 13:49:31.361;08;PBS_Server.25134;Job;11.headnode;Job Run at request of root@headnode
08/25/2017 13:49:31.374;13;PBS_Server.25134;Job;11.headnode;Not sending email: User does not want mail of this type.
08/25/2017 13:50:59.137;02;PBS_Server.25119;Svr;PBS_Server;Torque Server Version = 6.1.1.1, loglevel = 0
```

What could be the possible problem for which the job is stuck? To mention about the file "nodes", it is not also created.

pbsnodes -a gives the following output:

```
[root@headnode ~]# pbsnodes -a
headnode2
     state = free
     power_state = Running
     np = 22
     ntype = cluster
     jobs = 0-1/18.headnode
     status = opsys=linux,uname=Linux headnode2 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64,sessions=2406 3695 3699 3701 3731 3733 3757,nsessions=7,nusers=2,idletime=2901,totmem=82448372kb,availmem=80025348kb,physmem=49401852kb,ncpus=24,loadave=23.00,gres=,netload=1677000736,state=free,varattr= ,cpuclock=OnDemand:2301MHz,macaddr=34:40:b5:e5:4a:fa,version=6.1.1.1,rectime=1503919171,jobs=18.headnode
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003

headnode3
     state = free
     power_state = Running
     np = 22
     ntype = cluster
     jobs = 0-1/18.headnode
     status = opsys=linux,uname=Linux headnode3 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64,sessions=3570 3574 3576 3602 3604 3628 3803 32545,nsessions=8,nusers=3,idletime=882,totmem=98996200kb,availmem=97047600kb,physmem=65949680kb,ncpus=24,loadave=16.00,gres=,netload=1740623635,state=free,varattr= ,cpuclock=OnDemand:2301MHz,macaddr=34:40:b5:e5:43:52,version=6.1.1.1,rectime=1503919176,jobs=18.headnode
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003

headnode4
     state = free
     power_state = Running
     np = 22
     ntype = cluster
     status = opsys=linux,uname=Linux headnode4 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64,sessions=3592 4057 27119,nsessions=3,nusers=1,idletime=73567,totmem=98991080kb,availmem=96941208kb,physmem=65944560kb,ncpus=24,loadave=23.99,gres=,netload=727722516,state=free,varattr= ,cpuclock=OnDemand:2200MHz,macaddr=34:40:b5:e5:49:8a,version=6.1.1.1,rectime=1503919177,jobs=
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003

headnode5
     state = free
     power_state = Running
     np = 22
     ntype = cluster
     status = opsys=linux,uname=Linux headnode5 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64,sessions=17666,nsessions=1,nusers=1,idletime=2897,totmem=74170352kb,availmem=71840968kb,physmem=49397752kb,ncpus=24,loadave=23.04,gres=,netload=5756452931,state=free,varattr= ,cpuclock=OnDemand:2200MHz,macaddr=34:40:b5:e5:4a:a2,version=6.1.1.1,rectime=1503919174,jobs=
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003

headnode6
     state = free
     power_state = Running
     np = 22
     ntype = cluster
     status = opsys=linux,uname=Linux headnode6 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64,sessions=3678 24197,nsessions=2,nusers=1,idletime=70315,totmem=98991080kb,availmem=97279540kb,physmem=65944560kb,ncpus=24,loadave=16.00,gres=,netload=711846161,state=free,varattr= ,cpuclock=OnDemand:2200MHz,macaddr=34:40:b5:e5:44:52,version=6.1.1.1,rectime=1503919171,jobs=
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003
```

Comment: Would simple commands run, for example `mpirun -np 4 /bin/hostname` instead of `mpirun -np 4 gmx_mpi ...`?

Comment: It remains stuck... The thing is that we cannot get any help from the mpich-Torque/PBS mailing list because the list seems to be dead for a while now.

Comment: Nevertheless, the /bin/hostname job remains stuck

Comment: Are there any nodes available? What does `pbsnodes -a` report?

Comment: I included the `pbsnodes -a` output in the question... Please have a look... It properly shows the nodes and says they are free...

Comment: I guess the reason is that MPI is waiting to establish a connection between the two nodes allocated for the job. Could be a firewall issue. 1) Check if an MPI job would run if only one node is requested, i.e. `-l nodes=1:ppn=4`.

Comment: 2) Next step would be to ssh on one of the nodes allocated for the job, and see what processes are running, in what state. Next debugging MPI startup. Here the procedure depends on your MPI implementation.

Comment: In one node, the job completes after 2-3 seconds but is not giving out any output. To say about the firewall, during Torque setup, I included the ports in the iptables file as was suggested in the manual.

Comment: The problem is not with Torque, but with the MPI runtime communication between the nodes. If you are on a private LAN you could try to shutdown iptables on the nodes altogether and see if it would change anything. Another possibility: you did not setup passwordless SSH between the nodes and MPI is using SSH to start its processes. I will add the MPI tag to your post.

Comment: You are right... I did not setup passwordless ssh communication... Can you please tell me how to do that??? Or redirect me to any other thread???

Comment: The point is, I just tested, even the simple hostname command (without mpirun) is stuck...